# Google Cloud Tasks throttle calls to Cloud Run service

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run, google-cloud-tasks

I am experimenting with Google Cloud, and created the following mock stacked setup:

- **A** - Simple browser-based client with a button that sends a timestamp to **B** via websockets
- **B** - Client-facing Cloud Run endpoint that adds its own timestamp and sends it to **C**. This endpoint allows unauthenticated access.
- **C** - Service Cloud Run endpoint that receives the message from **B**, adds its own timestamp, and posts the result on Firestore. This endpoint requires authentication.

Once **C** submits a result on Firestore, **B** retrieves it using `onSnapshot`, adds yet another timestamp, and sends it back to the client via websockets.

I am comparing two invocation methods between **B** and **C** (i.e. inter-service communication):

- **Direct** invocation method, using `GoogleAuth` (code below)
- **Tasks** invocation method, using `CloudTasksClient` (code below)

On the client-side, I "warm up" the endpoints by clicking a few times, and then click 3 times in rapid succession. Here are my results.

```
# Direct Invocation Results

#1 ... [A→B=79ms] ... [B→C=24ms] ... [C→B=51ms]
#2 ... [A→B=75ms] ... [B→C=22ms] ... [C→B=67ms]
#3 ... [A→B=75ms] ... [B→C=23ms] ... [C→B=51ms]

# Cloud Tasks Invocation Results

#1 ... [A→B=106ms] ... [B→C=154ms] ... [C→B=53ms]
#2 ... [A→B=77ms] ... [B→C=984ms] ... [C→B=57ms]
#3 ... [A→B=78ms] ... [B→C=1815ms] ... [C→B=48ms]
```

**My question:** why does the **B→C** delay happen when using Cloud Tasks and is it possible to eliminate it?

It should be noted that the delay is noticeable to a human. It happens only when clicking on the button in rapid succession. I.e., when endpoint **B** has some tasks in the queue, as if Cloud Tasks processes requests sequentially one at a time.

The logs of the service endpoint **B** look like this (these do not correspond to the exact invocations above, but are typical):

```
# Direct invocation Logs
2022-07-18T20:48:36.133452Z POST 200 718 B 36 ms google-api-nodejs-client/8.1.0
2022-07-18T20:48:36.354304Z POST 200 718 B 19 ms google-api-nodejs-client/8.1.0
2022-07-18T20:48:36.377033Z POST 200 718 B 17 ms google-api-nodejs-client/8.1.0

# Cloud Tasks Invocation Logs
2022-07-18T20:50:10.848598Z POST 200 718 B 45 ms Google-Cloud-Tasks
2022-07-18T20:50:11.878559Z POST 200 718 B 19 ms Google-Cloud-Tasks
2022-07-18T20:50:12.825612Z POST 200 718 B 30 ms Google-Cloud-Tasks
```

Here is the Queue configuration:

```
Location: europe-west6

# Rate limits
Max rate: 500/s
Max concurrent: 5000
Max burst size: 100

# Retry parameters
Max attempts: 100
Min interval: 0.100s
Max interval: 3600s
Max doublings: 16
Max retry duration: Unlimited
```

With these rate limits and burst size I would expect not to have my tasks being throttled with so few tasks in the queue.

In case it matters, here is the code for invoking **B** directly:

```js
import {GoogleAuth} from "google-auth-library";

async function callDirect(endpoint, action, method, payload) {
  const options = {
    url: [endpoint, action].join('/'),
    method: method,
    data: JSON.stringify(payload),
  }

  const auth = new GoogleAuth();
  const client = await auth.getIdTokenClient(endpoint);
  await client.request(options);
}
```

and here is the code for invoking **B** through Cloud Tasks:

```js
import {CloudTasksClient} from "@google-cloud/tasks";

async function callCloudTasks(endpoint, action, method, queue, serviceAccountEmail, payload, delayInMs) {
  const httpRequest = {
    url: [endpoint, action].join('/'),
    httpMethod: method,
    body: Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(payload)).toString('base64'),
    oidcToken: {
      serviceAccountEmail: serviceAccountEmail
    }
  }

  const task = { httpRequest };

  if (delayInMs && delayInMs > 0) {
    task.scheduleTime = { seconds: (delayInMs + Date.now()) / 1000 }
  }

  const client = new CloudTasksClient();
  const parent = client.queuePath(process.env.GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT, process.env.GOOGLE_CLOUD_REGION, queue);

  const [response] = await client.createTask({ parent, task });
  return response;
}
```

**EDIT**

I enabled logs on the task queue, and I got 9 records for the 3 invocations:

```
2022-07-18T21:31:51.951028932Z ... task ... 80292792910020476731
2022-07-18T21:31:51.955891818Z ... attemptDispatchLog ... 80292792910020476731
2022-07-18T21:31:52.051478233Z ... attemptResponseLog ... 80292792910020476731
2022-07-18T21:31:52.117599641Z ... task ... 6381908289832183478
2022-07-18T21:31:52.320690636Z ... task ... 61642499052415748401
2022-07-18T21:31:52.955931232Z ... attemptDispatchLog ... 6381908289832183478
2022-07-18T21:31:53.020979257Z ... attemptResponseLog ... 6381908289832183478
2022-07-18T21:31:53.955947497Z ... attemptDispatchLog ... 61642499052415748401
2022-07-18T21:31:54.020855327Z ... attemptResponseLog ... 61642499052415748401
```

Here are the full 3 log records associated with last one, task ID `61642499052415748401`.

The `task` record:

```json
{
  "insertId": "vx94ynd6xcw",
  "jsonPayload": {
    "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.tasks.logging.v1.TaskActivityLog",
    "taskCreationLog": {
      "targetType": "HTTP",
      "scheduleTime": "2022-07-18T21:31:52.320189Z",
      "targetAddress": "POST [redacted]",
      "status": "OK"
    },
    "task": "projects/[redacted]/locations/europe-west6/queues/[redacted]/tasks/61642499052415748401"
  },
  "resource": {
    "type": "cloud_tasks_queue",
    "labels": {
      "project_id": "[redacted]",
      "location": "europe-west6",
      "queue_id": "[redacted]",
      "target_type": "HTTP"
    }
  },
  "timestamp": "2022-07-18T21:31:52.320690636Z",
  "severity": "INFO",
  "logName": "projects/[redacted]/logs/cloudtasks.googleapis.com%2Ftask_operations_log",
  "receiveTimestamp": "2022-07-18T21:31:53.529674798Z"
}
```

The `attemptDispatchLog` record:

```json
{
  "insertId": "17ka48kbh0",
  "jsonPayload": {
    "task": "projects/[redacted]/locations/europe-west6/queues/[redacted]/tasks/61642499052415748401",
    "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.tasks.logging.v1.TaskActivityLog",
    "attemptDispatchLog": {
      "targetType": "HTTP",
      "dispatchCount": "1",
      "targetAddress": "POST [redacted]",
      "dispatchReason": "PUSH_QUEUE",
      "maxAttempts": 0,
      "responseCount": "0",
      "scheduleTime": "2022-07-18T21:31:52.320189Z"
    }
  },
  "resource": {
    "type": "cloud_tasks_queue",
    "labels": {
      "location": "europe-west6",
      "target_type": "HTTP",
      "queue_id": "[redacted]",
      "project_id": "[redacted]"
    }
  },
  "timestamp": "2022-07-18T21:31:53.955947497Z",
  "severity": "INFO",
  "logName": "projects/[redacted]/logs/cloudtasks.googleapis.com%2Ftask_operations_log",
  "receiveTimestamp": "2022-07-18T21:31:54.415272458Z"
}
```

The `attemptResponseLog` record:

```json
{
  "insertId": "17ka48kbh1",
  "jsonPayload": {
    "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.tasks.logging.v1.TaskActivityLog",
    "attemptResponseLog": {
      "status": "OK",
      "scheduleTime": "2022-07-18T21:31:52.320189Z",
      "maxAttempts": 0,
      "targetAddress": "POST [redacted]",
      "dispatchCount": "1",
      "responseCount": "1",
      "targetType": "HTTP"
    },
    "task": "projects/[redacted]/locations/europe-west6/queues/[redacted]/tasks/61642499052415748401"
  },
  "resource": {
    "type": "cloud_tasks_queue",
    "labels": {
      "location": "europe-west6",
      "target_type": "HTTP",
      "queue_id": "[redacted]",
      "project_id": "[redacted]"
    }
  },
  "timestamp": "2022-07-18T21:31:54.020855327Z",
  "severity": "INFO",
  "logName": "projects/[redacted]/logs/cloudtasks.googleapis.com%2Ftask_operations_log",
  "receiveTimestamp": "2022-07-18T21:31:54.415272458Z"
}
```

Comment: When you use Cloud Task, should I understand that flow: B -> Cloud Task -> C? And do you compare it to a direct flow, like that B -> C ? If so, it's normal that is slower, but your 900ms and 1800ms are weird. Did you try that scenario over a long period of time (10 or 20 minutes) with sustainable traffic? Does it work better (lower latency) after a long period?

Comment: Yes, you understand correctly. I observe this behavior consistently whenever I try, even after numerous warm up clicks when cloud run containers are active. It doesn’t work better after awhile. Typically, what gets better after one or two warm up clicks with sufficient gap between them is that the first click in a series gets lower latency. But the second and third click in a series always get throttled.

Comment: hmmm, strange. It wasn't to test the container warm up, because you should also have that latency without Cloud Task. My assumption was that there could have a endpoint latency observer. Quicker the endpoint answer, faster the delivery is. But no. I have no clue.

Comment: It’s correct - I’m seeing the same “warm up” latency regardless of invocation method (both direct and cloud tasks), which is expected. But the throttling post-warm up starting with the second message happens only when I’m using cloud tasks. As if cloud task enforces a processing limit of 1 task at a time.

Comment: But, Why are you using Task in that architecture? What's the value added?

Comment: I’m currently only testing different approaches for inter service communication as part of architecture investigation for a larger project. I like the idea of cloud tasks as the caller receives an immediate confirmation from the cloud tasks service, while in direct invocation the HTTP socket is waiting until the server responds. Also, cloud tasks has a retry mechanism baked in, which can be convenient.

Comment: To perform async communication like that, prefer PubSub. Cloud task is perfect for delaying a message in the future or the control the throttle (rate limit) of the consumer.

Comment: Thanks, I will do a similar test on pubsub.

Comment: Did a similar experiment for Pubsub. In my test, Direct invocation had an average latency of 25ms between B > C. When I tested with B > pubsub > C, the average latency was 147ms. Unlike Cloud Tasks, Pubsub does not throttle calls. I.e., when I clicked on the button that starts the process in rapid succession, messages came back pretty much in parallel (while in Cloud Tasks, per the main point of this question, all calls were processed one at a time, with about 830ms gap in between each one).